# Operational Error: no such column:vkid

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Работаю с CGI Python. И столкнулся с проблемой.
Не записывает в базу данных переменные. Не могу понять почему, пишет что нет столбца, хотя он есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi
import vk
import random
import sqlite3
import os.path

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "database.db")

con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cur = con.cursor()

access_token = "censored"
session = vk.Session(access_token=access_token)
api = vk.API(session)

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
vkid = form.getvalue('vkid')
qiwi = form.getvalue("qiwi")

uid = random.randint(1000,9999)

def add_user(vkid,qiwi,uid):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO database VALUES (vkid , qiwi , uid)", (vkid, qiwi, uid))
    con.commit()

def getUserId(link):
    id = link
    if 'vk.com/' in link: #  проверяем эту ссылку
        id = link.split('/')[-1]  # 
    if not id.replace('id', '').isdigit(): # е
        id = api.utils.resolveScreenName(screen_name=id, v=5.8)['object_id']
    else:
        id = id.replace('id', '')
    return int(id)

vkid = getUserId(vkid)

add_user(vkid,qiwi,uid)
```

Comment: Вот так: `INSERT INTO database VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO database VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```